# FullCalendar backend PHP/JS to symfony 3

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

I needs calendar who will be worked as below:

Backend:

I clicked chosen field, and I will be redirected to createAction event
if I clicked chosen event, it will should redirect to  editing this event action

Frontend;

user clicked choosen event and he will be redirect to  site where will be can save on the event.

I thought about this, but  do  I will be able do this? 
https://jquery.com/download/

Answer (score 1):

You can define what to do when the user [click](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/) an event

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

        //Edit your event

}
```

});

or [click](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/dayClick/) somewhere where there are no events :

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {

        //createAction
    }
});
```